# Find if std::list contains element from another std::list

Tags: c++

I have two lists:

```
std::list<MyClass1> listClass1;
std::list<MyClass2> listClass2;
```

For sake of simplicity lets say that they have these elements:

```
listClass1

{id: 1, name: "Test1"}
{id: 2, name: "Test2"}
{id: 3, name: "Test3"}
{id: 4, name: "Test4"}
{id: 5, name: "Test5"}

listClass2

{id: 1, name: "Test2"}
{id: 2, name: "Test5"}
```

I need to find out if `listClass2` `name` property is in `listClass1` `name`. I mean, if they match. Otherwise return an error or -1.

Is there a more efficient way than looping twice? That's all I could think of at the moment, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: If the containers are sorted you can use [`std::set_union`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store one (larger of the two would be better) of the list's names into a `set<string>` and iterate over the other list and see if the set contains that element.

That should reduce your running time from O(m * n) to O(m * log(n)).

P.S.: I believe using a hash table can further reduce that log(n) factor.

Comment: `std::unordered_set` . We don't care about order; only about presence.

Comment: Definitely use `unordered_set` in that case since it will provide constant time lookup.